# Spring-boot with Tapestry configuration

Tags: java, user-interface, spring-boot, tapestry

Does anyone have any reference project with Spring-boot and Tapestry5? I can't seem to find any samples.
I have diificulties in configuring the tapestry bean & Context using a @configuration class without an web.xml.

Comment: This question is a little general, but not too too general. In the future, provide a bit of info about what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks Chase. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're looking for https://github.com/trust-wenderson/tapestry-spring

Comment: Hi Chase. Thanks for the link. I see there is a web.xml. It is NOT spring-boot specific.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for such an example myself, and I happen to have found one today:

https://github.com/code8/tapestry-boot

> The **tapestry-boot** library implements following features:
>
> - bootstraps tapestry framework inside embedded servlet container managed by **spring-boot**
> - provides injection of spring-services into tapestry-services
> - provides injection of tapestry-services into spring-services
>
> To use **tapestry-boot** simple marks tapestry application module with
>   @TapestryApplication annotation.
>
> See DemoApplicationTests.

Comment: I've tested "tapestry-boot" on Tapestry 5.4.1 archetype sample project and so far it really works great! I like the fact that it requires minimum effort to run this thing. Just put some dependencies, annotate tapestry module, move static resources to `main/resources/META-INF/asserts` and voila!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Register `TapestrySpringFilter`

```
    @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean tapesSpringFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new TapestrySpringFilter());
    registration.setName("app");
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
    return registration;
}
```

Add context aprameters to `application.yml`

```
server:
  context_parameters:
    tapestry:
      use-external-spring-context: true
      app-package: com.test.admin
      development-modules: ...
      qa-modules: ...
```

I also had to use executable War to avoid problems with loading static files.

Perhaps this approach will not allow you to access the tapestry beans from the spring context.